# Returning object-parameter in Web-Flow

Tags: java, spring, spring-webflow

I have the following files:

**webflow-context.xml**

```
...
<bean id="user" class="com.bla-bla.datamodel.User" scope="prototype" />
...
```

**User.java**

```
public class User implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private Integer id;
    private String name;
    private Address address = new Address();
    //setters and getters
}
```

**addUser.jspx**

```
...
<form:form commandName="user">
        <form:hidden path="id" />
                    <form:input path="name"/>
                    <form:input path="address.street"/>
          <div class="Buttons">
            <div class="Button">
                <button type="submit" name="_eventId_cancelUser">
                    <fmt:message key="button.cancel" />
                </button>
                <button type="submit" name="_eventId_userNext">
                    <fmt:message key="button.next" />
                </button>
            </div>
        </div>
</form:form>
...
```

**addUser.xml**

```
    <on-start>
        <set name="flowScope.user" value="user" />
    </on-start>

    <view-state id="addUser" view="addUser">
        <transition on="cancelUser" to="cancelUser"/>
        <transition on="userNext" to="userNext">
            <set name="user.name" value="requestParameters.name"/>
            <set name="user.address.street" value="requestParameters.address.street"/>
        </transition>
    </view-state>
...
```

The problem is that  works correctly but  has error:

```
org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Request processing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.webflow.execution.ActionExecutionException: Exception thrown executing [AnnotatedAction@741dbf43 targetAction = [SetAction@4cf80343 name = user.address.street, value = requestParameters.address.street], attributes = map[[empty]]] in state ' addUser ' of flow ' addUser ' -- action execution attributes were 'map[[empty]]'
org.springframework.webflow.execution.ActionExecutionException: Exception thrown executing [AnnotatedAction@741dbf43 targetAction = [SetAction@4cf80343 name = user.address.street, value = requestParameters.address.street], attributes = map[[empty]]] in state ' addUser ' of flow ' addUser ' -- action execution attributes were 'map[[empty]]'
org.springframework.binding.expression.EvaluationException: An ELException occurred getting the value for expression 'requestParameters.address.street' on context [class org.springframework.webflow.engine.impl.RequestControlContextImpl]
org.springframework.expression.spel.SpelEvaluationException: EL1007E:(pos 0): Field or property 'street' cannot be found on null
```

If the field «User» is an object, I get the error.
My job is simply to get the data entered on the page and save it in bean user (flowScope.user) that would be the last step process them.

How to do it right?

UPD:I found my problem, even after `<form:input path="address.street"/>` address = NULL. But why?

Answer (score 0):

i think the problem is here: `value="requestParameters.address.street"`

`requestParameters` can only contain Strings and you expect an object of the type `Address`

Simply pass your street like this `...&name=foo&street=bar...` in your url
and receive it as `requestParameters.street`